# Groovy GPars, need index for each thread launched

Tags: groovy, concurrency, indexing, threadpool, gpars

Using GPars with Groovy, I launch 3 threads to do some work in parallel...

```
 GParsPool.withPool(3){ 
   result = myList.collectParallel{
      processItem(it)
   }
 }
```

This works fine, but I need an index in the closure that represents the thread number launched. Not sure how to access such an index since there is no loop; everything is happening in parallel.

I tried using `eachWithIndexParallel`, this, but Groovy complains of no such method for (ArrayList, Integer)

```
GParsPool.withPool(3) {
    result = myList.eachWithIndexParallel{ i -> 
        processItem( it, i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eachWithIndex() in Groovy passes two arguments to the closure and returns no result:
GParsPool.withPool(3) {
    myList.eachWithIndexParallel{e, i -> 
        processItem( e, i)
    }
}
which explains, why it cannot find the method.

Special care, however, needs to be taken to get the results out of the each in a thread-safe way.

One way to get the identification of the thread processing an element is to query the Thread.currentThread() method inside the closure.

Comment: @Vaclac Played around with last night, and you're right, `eachWithIndexParallel` does not collect the results, so I'm sticking with `collectParallel` to avoid explicit concurrency handling...A question: how did you know `eachWithIndexParallel` requires two arguments? Where can I find that info?

Comment: Documenting such things (the expected number or type of arguments of closures passed into methods) in Groovy is difficult, in general. For this particular case, eachWithIndexParallel() just follows the contract of the original sequential eachWithIndex() method from Groovy.

Comment: Documentation : http://gpars.org/1.2.1/groovydoc/groovyx/gpars/Parallel.html#eachWithIndexParallel%28groovy.lang.Closure%29